# insert into in node red

Tags: sql, node-red

edited

I'm getting a string variable from a plc in node red via node "s7", the variable should be inserted into a MySQL DB, through the function node I tried to create a "insert into" query but in the database the string appears undefined, I'm new on node red and I do not know what I was wrong with the query below

```
msg.topic = 
  "INSERT INTO S7_log(commessa_in_produzione) VALUES" + 
  ('"+msg.payload.commessa_in_produzione+"')";


return msg;
```

[image: this is the output that I've received, the value was: "BAD48"]

Comment: You haven't shown the code that *executes* that query. In any case using dynamic SQL is a serious problem. Imagine if that property contained even a single `'`, you'd get an invalid query. Or worse, a SQL Injection. Google for `Bobby Tables`.What if `commessa_in_produzione` contained `'; drop table S7_log;-- ` ?

Comment: Edit the question to show the output of the S7 node so we can see what the input to the function node is

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos With the output coming from the S7 node in Node-RED there is no way for a 3rd party to manipulate the variable as you describe, it is not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the incoming message it appears you want to use the `msg.payload.signal` field which will insert into the database the value "Commessa in produzione"

So the function should look like:

```
msg.topic = 
  "INSERT INTO S7_log(commessa_in_produzione) VALUES" + 
  ('"+msg.payload.signal+"')";


return msg;
```

Comment: There are also unbalanced double-quotes in the original code -- the continuation line needs a `"` before the open parenthesis.